# Can Python write to database and Meteor reactively update

Tags: python, node.js, mongodb, meteor

Can Python be writing data to a database (mongdb) and have Meteor receive updates of the database writes and update the frontend?

Comment: Yes, but it will take a few seconds to sync (meteor uses polling). Write your `_id`s as strings instead of using `ObjectId`s.

Comment: @DavidWeldon will it work if the _ids are integers rather than strings?

Comment: @Curious2learn Because this isn't the convention, I can't say if its a good idea or not. However, I did a quick test and using integers appears to work (the objects arrived on the client and the client could update them).

Answer (score 3):

Meteor 0.7.2 and later implements this functionality fully via the [oplog observe driver](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver). Writes to Mongo are **immediately** reflected on any Meteor servers backed by the database.

This is achieved by having Meteor watch the operations in the Mongo oplog, so that any database operations are incorporated into live data cursors immediately. In previous versions of Meteor, this happened via polling, which could take up to 10 seconds for data to propagate. However, everything is now immediate with the latest driver.