# Meteor how to run server side python script

Tags: javascript, python, meteor

I have a Meteor app that needs to call a python script to do some stuff in the background. How can I get this to work? I've tried using child_process and exec, but I can't seem to get it to execute properly. Where should the script even be located?

Thanks

Comment: Seems [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011443/best-way-to-get-python-and-meteor-talking) is what are you looking for

Comment: I've tried using that, but where should my script be located?

Comment: away from the scope of the meteor project outside the project would be a nice place, btw did you get a solution for the other 2 questions? about mongo and python? there is not to much information over here to accomplish that, if you find a workaround please post it =D

Comment: Hmm I still don't think it's working... in the exec function, what exactly am I putting? Is it a python command? and how can I tell if it was successful?

Answer (score 3):

I have same problems and its solved use python-sheel an npm packages to run Python scripts from Node.js 
Install on meteor :

```
meteor npm install --save python-shell
```

There is simple usage :

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

PythonShell.run('my_script.py', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
});
```

If you want run with arguments and options :

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

var options = {
  mode: 'text',
  pythonPath: 'path/to/python',
  pythonOptions: ['-u'],
  scriptPath: 'path/to/my/scripts',
  args: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
};

PythonShell.run('my_script.py', options, function (err, results) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
  console.log('results: %j', results);
});
```

here detail about python-shell https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell
Thanks extrabacon :)