# What is the best way to integrate numpy into a meteorjs web app?

Tags: python, numpy, meteor

I've just started to poke around MeteorJS and it looks great. However the app I'm starting to build has a scientific component which i would prefer to implement using numpy/scipy/pandas.

Is there an idiomatic approach to leveraging a computationally intensive (I'm also toying with a separate app using OpenCV) component in conjunction with MeteorJS?

Comment: Chris, Does this question scratch your same itch? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011443/best-way-to-get-python-and-meteor-talking - Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

I use [vsivsi/meteor-job-collection](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection) for time intensive tasks. I currently run the workers via [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) on a single server with my application, though pm2 can be made to run on separate servers to scale.